# Sharp Architecture Simple CRUD Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sharp-architecture

i am trying to get start with the Sharp Architecture by building the test application mentioned [**here**](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/wiki/Simple-crud-application), i have followed through the steps given in the tutorial but hit a road block where the database schema generation is described. According to the tutorial running the test

```
IceCreamYouScreamCorp.Tests.SharpArchTemplate.Data.NHibernateMaps.CanGenerateDatabaseSchema
```

will generate the schema in the Database folder, i couldn't find this test in the generate application by [Templify](http://weblogs.asp.net/alecwhittington/archive/2010/10/10/using-templify-to-create-a-new-s-arp-architecture-solution.aspx). Please anybody who knows the solution guide me how to run this test so to generate the database schema...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be i have not pharsed the question well enough, i have figured out the solution

1. download the [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) framework
2. runt the test by using the NUnit

it will create the desired database schema for the sample application

Comment: I have the same problem. How do you run the test? What files?

Comment: after downloading the nunit browse the web solution dir for the Test.dll(don't exactly remem the name) load it in the NUnit and hit run

Comment: I know this post is a little old, but I ran into the same issue which was caused by selecting "2.0.0.3" from the Templify dropdown rather than 2.0.0.0. Selecting that copied in some extra files, one of them being the unit tests to setup the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you tryed to use the version 2.0.0.3, you will have this problem.
Try to select the "2.0.0.0" option on Templify.
To run the test, open NUnit GUI, and go to the following folder and open the .dll file:

```
[Your_Templifyed_Folder]\Solutions\[Your_Solution_Name].Tests\bin\Debug\[Your_Solution_Name].Tests.dll
```

Now you can see the right tests list in the NUnit interface.